# Position div below responsive inline-block divs

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, position

I have a grid of divs, each responsive to the browser size so that their width changes *in proportion* to their height (their ratio stays the same). I'd like a separate div (its height determined only by the text it contains) to sit underneath all these, creating additional space for itself at the foot of the page. At the moment it sits under the first row. Is there a solution?

Thanks for your help.

https://jsfiddle.net/Ly008adL/

CSS:

```
* {
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
}

.wrapper {
width: 100%;
display: inline-block;
position: relative;
}

.wrapper:after {
padding-top: 71%;
display: block;
content: '';
}

.main {
position: absolute;
top: 0;
bottom: 0;
right: 0;
left: 0;
}

.ratio {
display: inline-flex;
float: left;
width: 50%;
height: 100%;
}

.red {
background-color: red;
}

.yel {
background-color: yellow;
}

.foot {
position: relative;
}
```

HTML:

```
<div class="wrapper">
<div class="main">
    <div class="ratio yel"></div>
    <div class="ratio red"></div>
    <div class="ratio red"></div>
    <div class="ratio yel"></div>
    <div class="ratio yel"></div>
    <div class="ratio red"></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="foot">
<p>Text for the foot of the page </p>
</div>
```

A friend helped me figure out a potential solution involving dividing the height by the number of rows, but I'm not sure on the total number of rows yet so something more flexible would be ideal...

Comment: You are using the ratio trick on the `.wrapper` not on the elements with the class `.ratio`. Is this on purpose? Something more like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly008adL/1/) maybe

Comment: If it needs to be moved it can be - so long as all the coloured divs hold their shape.

Comment: Like [this](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly008adL/2/) then?

Comment: Er, yes! Thank you! That was very simple. Can I give you credit for answering if it's posted as a commend?

Comment: I can post an answer for people looking at this in the future

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [css ratio trick](http://www.mademyday.de/css-height-equals-width-with-pure-css.html) you are using was being applied to the `.wrapper` and not the individual elements.

I simply removed it from the `.wrapper` and applied it to the individual `.ratio` elements. I also had to double the `padding-top` from 71% to 142% to maintain the right ratio because these elements were 50% width and not 100% like the `.wrapper` was.

I also changed the `.main` div to `position:relative;` so that all the children would render out properly and so the `.foot` div would render after it.

See the updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/Ly008adL/2/).